# If $z=f(x,y$) where $x=e^u \cos(v)$ and $y=e^u \sin(v)$ then the value of $y\frac{∂z}{∂u}+x\frac{∂z}{∂v}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> **If $z=f(x,y$) where $x=e^u \cos(v)$ and $y=e^u \sin(v)$ then the
>   value  of**
>
> **$y\frac{∂z}{∂u}+x\frac{∂z}{∂v}$ is**
>
> $(A)e^{2u}\frac{∂z}{∂y}\quad(B) e^{2u}\frac{∂z}{∂x}\quad (C)e^{2u}(\frac{∂z}{∂x}+\frac{∂z}{∂y})\quad (D)0$

I tried it by applying the chain rule

$y\frac{∂z}{∂u}=y\frac{∂z}{∂x}\frac{∂x}{∂u} \tag{1}$

$x\frac{∂z}{∂v}=x\frac{∂z}{∂y}\frac{∂y}{∂u}. \tag{2}$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$y\frac{∂z}{∂u}+x\frac{∂z}{∂v}=y\frac{∂z}{∂x}\frac{∂x}{∂u}+x\frac{∂z}{∂y}\frac{∂y}{∂u}\tag{3}.$

As $\frac{∂x}{∂u}=e^u \cos(v)$ & $\frac{∂y}{∂v}=e^u \cos(v)$, putting these values in $(3)$, we get

> ***$y\frac{∂z}{∂u}+x\frac{∂z}{∂v}=e^u \cos(v)[y\frac{∂z}{∂x}+x\frac{∂z}{∂y}].$***

My answer is not matching with any of the given options.

**Where I'm committing mistake??**

Comment: You're missing a component: $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z$ is a function of two independent variable $x$ and $y$, so 
$\frac{∂z}{∂u}=\frac{∂z}{∂x}\frac{∂x}{∂u}+\frac{∂z}{∂y}\frac{∂y}{∂u} \tag{1}$
and similarly 
$\frac{∂z}{∂v}=\frac{∂z}{∂x}\frac{∂x}{∂v}+\frac{∂z}{∂y}\frac{∂y}{∂v}. \tag{2}$ 
Here you are wrong. For more details see the [pdf](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS4_nF7rTZAhXHmpQKHXZUD40QFgg-MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwwwf.imperial.ac.uk%2F~jdg%2FAECHAIN.PDF&usg=AOvVaw2Ol6Nc01O3UxFq44DMgCSM).

Therefore using $(1)$ and $(2)$, $yz_u+xz_v=e^uz_x(e^usinv~cosv-e^ucosv~sinv)+e^uz_y(e^usinv~sinv+e^ucosv~cosv)=e^{2u}z_y$.

Hence option $(A)$ is true.